# Try and catch in MysqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery in insert MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, mysql-error-1064

When I insert a null it shows an error in my code. Can I try and catch it? I don't know how.

```
Call Connects()
MySqlCmd = New MySqlCommand
MySqlCmd.Connection = Myconnect
MySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select ID,ItemName,Quantity,ItemDesc,SuppInfo,datee from item "
MyDA = New MySqlDataAdapter
myDataTable = New DataTable
MyDA.SelectCommand = MySqlCmd
MyDA.Fill(myDataTable)
MySqlCmd = New MySqlCommand
MySqlCmd.Connection = Myconnect
MySqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO item(ID,ItemName,Quantity,ItemDesc,SuppInfo,Po_Number,datee) VALUES('" & TextBox7.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "','" & TextBox6.Text & "',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"
MySqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
MsgBox("New working", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
```

Is there anything I can do?

Here is a screenshot which shows the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your value of TextBox3.Text and if it cannot be parsed to int, replace it with 0. If you want insert NULL specify it precisely, not with empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```
  If Label30.Text = 1 Then
            Try
                If TextBox7.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Or TextBox4.Text = "" Or TextBox5.Text = "" Or TextBox6.Text = "" Then
                    MessageBox.Show("ERROR!")
                ElseIf TextBox7.TextLength > 0 And TextBox2.TextLength > 0 And TextBox3.TextLength > 0 And TextBox4.TextLength > 0 And TextBox5.TextLength > 0 And TextBox6.TextLength > 0 Then
                    Call Connects()
                    MySqlCmd = New MySqlCommand
                    MySqlCmd.Connection = Myconnect
                    MySqlCmd.CommandText = "Select ID,ItemName,Quantity,ItemDesc,SuppInfo,datee from item "
                    MyDA = New MySqlDataAdapter
                    myDataTable = New DataTable
                    MyDA.SelectCommand = MySqlCmd
                    MyDA.Fill(myDataTable)
```

its working now thankyou :) this is how i solve my own problem.